# How to use the User value resolver in Symfony 3.2?

Tags: symfony

I'm building a small website using symfony 3.2.

There is a page in which the user can change its profile data with a form. I used the structure seen in the [official tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object). Here is the declaration of my controller :

```
/** @Route("/profil", name="profil_show_user") */
public function userProfileAction(Request $request, UserInterface $user) {
    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
    //...
    $user->getProfile();//and do stuff
    //...
}
```

My problem is that if the user is disconnected for being inactive for too long, or if someone bookmark the page but is not connected, I have this ugly error coming :

> Controller
>   "AppBundle\Controller\ProfilController::userProfileAction()" requires
>   that you provide a value for the "$user" argument. Either the argument
>   is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has
>   been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this
>   one. 500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException

In the [New in Symfony 3.2](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers) changelog, there is something about the new User value resolver. I tried to change to `UserInterface $user = null`, and it make the page redirect to the path I set in `failure_path` of security.yml, which is the good behaviour.

But then if I'm connected and go to `profil_show_user`, I get that other error :

> Error: Call to a member function getProfile() on null

I search thoroughly the symfony documentation but couldn't find anything.

Could someone explain to me what goes wrong, what I misunderstood and how can I make this work ?

**EDIT :**

I thought I might say that if I don't use te value resolver, everything works fine. This is an educationnal and curiosity question about a new feature which I don't manage to use. This code works :

```
/** @Route("/profil", name="profil_show_user") */
public function userProfileAction(Request $request) { 
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
    //...
    $user->getProfile();//and do stuff
    //...
}
```

Comment: you should do a check: `if ($user) { $user->getProfile(); }`

Comment: My problem is not that I cannot read the profile, but that my user is null even if it is connected. I understood the `UserInterface $user = null` as a default value if there is no user but when I test the user is always null

Comment: Try: UserInterface $user = $this->getUser()

Comment: You cannot use $this in a method signature. Plus, `Controller::getUser()` is deprecated.

Comment: so try this: UserInterface $user = null

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#always-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in

Comment: All the second part of my post is about what happen when I do that... (after "in the new symfony 3.2...")

Comment: I'm not so sure, but doesn't Symfony redirect the user, automatically, to the /login page, if the session has expired?

Comment: It seems not, at least in dev mode. But even if it would, get to the path without beeing connected end in an error, not a redirection, which is completely wrong